# bootstrap-multiselect onDropdownShow doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

Using davidstutz's bootstrap-multiselect plugin with twitter bootstrap 3.3.0.
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect

My purpose is that when i click on the dropdown, i'd like to get a radio button selected, but it doesn't work.

**HTML (blade):**

```
{{Form::radio('radio', 'value', null, array('id' => 'radioID' ,'class' => 'name', 'autocomplete' => 'off'))}}

{{Form::select('select', $valuesArray,'', array('id' => 'selectID' ,'multiselect' => 'multiselect', 'class' => 'msdropdown', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'autocomplete' => 'off'))}}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectID').multiselect({
        onDropdownShow: function(event){
            $('#radioID').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

------------Update-------------

The problem was it was duplicately initialized, before the ('#selectID') section. I removed first one and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Shouldn't `$('#radio').prop('checked', true);` be `$('#radioID').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes. But still it is not getting triggered. Editing the post.

Answer (score 0):

Its `onDropdownShown` not `onDropdownShow`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectID').multiselect({
        onDropdownShown: function(event){
            $('#radioID').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

**[`Source`](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onDropdownShown)**

Comment: In documentation, both onDropdownShown and onDropdownShow is available. Despite I've tried both, didn't get it triggered.

Comment: @blankBird_ Place an `alert` inside `onDropdownShown` and check if its triggered...

Comment: that's how i checked it is not getting triggered, even tried console.log(). I'm missing something or there's something else.

Comment: Is it possible to replicate it in `fiddle`?

Comment: I've solved the problem. The reason it wasn't working was i had initialized all the multiselect elements by class, before the $('$selectID').multiselect call.

Comment: Cool.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try Each operation like this :

```
$('#selectID').multiselect({
        onDropdownShown: function(event){
                  $('#selectID option').each(function () {
                         var rad = $(this).find('#radioID')[0];
                         $(rad).prop('checked', true);
                 }
        }
    });
```